# как настроить NamingStrategy для newtonsoft json динамически?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть redmine. У него есть API. API этот для единичного элемента выглядит так

```
{
  "issue": { ... }
}
```

где "issue" это тип возвращаемой сущности. Для другой сущности это будет другое значение. Я хочу десериализовать это в тип

```
public class SingleEntity<T>
{
    public T Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Где `T` будет типом сущности. Понятное дело, в свойство Entity так просто ничего не десериализуется. Через `NamingStrategy` сделать не получится, потому что для именования мне потребуется тип `T`, но передать его в `NamingStrategyParameters` я не могу, потому что в атрибуте нельзя указывать `typeof(T)`.

Вариант с ручной десериализацией через JObject мне не очень нравится. Хотя бы потому, что следующим шагом будет десериализация коллекций, а там все немного сложнее. В итоге код не будет выглядеть очевидным.

Вот я и подумал, может есть возможность настройки сериализации/десериализации для newtonsoft json в рантайме?

Comment: там разве на одну и ту же конечную точку разные типы возвращаются?

Comment: @tym32167, нет, но у всех возвращаемых json есть особенность, сущности завернуты в { "entitytype": {}}

Comment: ну то есть вы до вызова API уже по сути знаете структуру, что вам приедет, так?

Comment: @tym32167, да знаю.

Comment: ну так и дерериализуйте в нужный тип, какие с этим проблемы?

Comment: @tym32167, я не хочу десериализовать вручную. Я хочу JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>()

Comment: ну так и делайте `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectResponse>` или `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IssueResponse>`

Comment: @tym32167, тут на каждую сущность тогда будут классы Entity, EntityResponse и EntityCollection. Хотелось бы обойтись Entity, Response<T> и ResponseCollection<T>

Comment: но это ведь по сути разные респонсы, у них разные свойства и разные объекты по этим свойствам.

Comment: @tym32167, общая суть одна. У Response<T> будет свойство "entityname": { my entity properties }, а у ResponseCollection<T> { "entitynames": [entities array], total: int, limit: int }

Comment: @tym32167 в общем json serializer при десериализации смотрит на имя свойства, а мне надо чтобы он смотрел на тип. Но я не могу в аттрибут JsonPropertyAttribute подкинуть typeof(T). но мне бы очень хотелось :) Поэтому ищу альтернативу. Чтобы на 5 сущностей у меня было не 15 классов, а 7 (5 моделей и 2 дженерика)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы ищете что то вроде этого:

Допустим есть класс

```
public class SingleResponse<T>
{       
    public T Entity {get;set;}
}
```

И вы определили типы

```
public class Issue
{
    [JsonProperty("project_id")]
    public int ProjectId{get;set;}

    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Есть Json типа

```
string issueJ= @"{
  ""issue"": {
    ""project_id"": 1,
    ""subject"": ""Example"",
    ""priority_id"": 4
  }
}";

string userJ =  @"{
    ""user"": {
        ""login"": ""jplang"",
        ""firstname"": ""Jean-Philippe"",
        ""lastname"": ""Lang"",
        ""mail"": ""jp_lang@yahoo.fr"",
        ""password"": ""secret"" 
    }
}";
```

Тогда настрочим резолвер

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private string _propertyName;
    public CustomContractResolver(string propertyName)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }   
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);        

        if (property.PropertyName == "Entity")
        property.PropertyName = _propertyName;

        return property;
    }
}
```

и будем им пользоваться вот так

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver("issue")
};
var issue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleResponse<Issue>>(issueJ, serializerSettings);
Console.WriteLine(issue.Entity.Subject);



serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver("user")
};
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleResponse<User>>(userJ, serializerSettings);
Console.WriteLine(user.Entity.Login);
```

На выходе получим

```
Example
jplang
```

Мопед не мой, собран по мотивам [этого поста](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633105/312041)

Comment: Еще вопрос. А можно serializerSettings для каждого типа настроить глобально? Чтобы я вызывал `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleResponse<Issue>>(issueJ)`  без настроек? Ну типа как настраиваются профили для автомаппера.

Comment: Нет пока компьютера под рукой, но вы можете поглядеть на [это](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm)